# Issue with UITableViewCell and Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to create a custom cell with 4 `UILabels` and a `UITextView`. I've laid out the elements. The `UITextView` is not scrollable. The problem I face it placing the last `UILabel` under the `UITextView`. I've tried pinning both(either) to the superview and nothing seems to work. It is always under the `UITextView` no matter what as shown below:

[image: Screenshot]

What more should I do to move the UILabel below the UITextView?

This the only change I've made in my code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    QXTInboxCell *inboxCell = (QXTInboxCell*)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGFloat width = self.tableView.frame.size.width - inboxCell.question.frame.origin.x - QUESTION_RIGHT_MARGIN;
    CGSize size = [inboxCell.question sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, 400)];

    [inboxCell.question sizeThatFits:size];
    return (inboxCell.question.frame.origin.y + size.height + 20);
}
```

Please help. I'm on XCode 5.0.2. Thanks.

Comment: Pin the label's bottom edge to the superview? Also, you're programming bad if you're getting errors like those I see in the screenshot. Your cell also seems over-constrained. Some of them might be broken at runtime. Check the console for constraint-related errors.

Comment: I tried pinning it to the superview. Doesnt help.

Comment: Paste all your console output here.

Comment: I'm getting errors and crashes from time to time like so assertion on /SourceCache/MobileDataDetectorsCore_Sim/MobileDataDetectorsCore-355/Sources/PushDown/DDTokenCache.c:360 "delta >= 0" failed :Bad shift in DDTokenCacheMoveStreamOffset, aborting. But, rerunning the app, makes it go away

Comment: That's not what I mean. The error in your screenshot, "Unbalanced…" and any constraint-related errors.

Comment: That was actually coz of another method that I shouldnt have been calling. Commented that out

Comment: Okay… got that. Are there any **constraints-related** errors in the console?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42851/discussion-between-anil-and-duci9y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following constraints:

- TextView to superview (top space)
- TextView to label (bottom/top space)
- label to superview (bottom space)

then (AFTER you set the text of the textView) call

```
[cell setNeedsLayout]
```

Of course this only works if you calculated the correct height for the cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Thanks. That almost fixed the problem. Now the UILabel has moved down but hasnt moved down completely. The UITextView still clips half of the UILabel

Comment: Are you sure the height of the cell is correct? Try adding some bottom margin, does it work then?

Comment: Kindof solves the problem. But the issue is, with small text in the UITextView, it disappears completely